# Frame Load Interrupted: Safari won't download a linked zip file from my Flash site

Tags: actionscript-3, safari

First of all I am a total noob so I apologize if this is a dumb question.  I am building a Flash site that is designed to be used offline, on a private network.  I have successfully linked PDF files, which Safari opens in the browser.  This is fine because the file can still be saved from there.  However, now I am trying to link .zip files and .mp4/.mov files and am encountering some issues.

Firefox and Safari both try to play the movie files in the browser, but I would prefer for the Open/Save dialog box to appear.  As far as .zip files, Firefox prompts the dialog box, which is what I want; in Safari, a new window appears yet nothing happens.  The activity window says "Frame Load Interrupted."  I have researched this issue and tried tinkering with Safari settings but nothing has worked, nor am I sure it's solely a Safari issue, or if there is something I can do with the Actionscript to prompt the download dialog box.  I have seen some different code options for file downloads but wasn't sure how to implement them correctly, or if that was even necessary in my case.  Right now I am most familiar with URLRequest and have successfully used the two following configurations:

1)
    var zipURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Archive.zip");

```
function launchdownload(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(zipURL, "_blank");
}
btn_name.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,launchdownload);
```

2)
    var request:URLRequest;
    var localRef:FileReference;

```
btn_name.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,downloadFile);

function downloadFile (evtObj:Event):void 
{
    var Location:URLRequest = new URLRequest            
     ("../Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Archive.zip");
    navigateToURL (Location, "_new");
}
```

If anyone can help me to get around the Frame Load Interrupted issue and/or show me how to properly code my download button such that I can force the Open/Save dialog in all browsers, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also let ActionScript do the downloading.
If you add the following code you get a dialog box that lets you select a location to download your file and downloads it.

```
btn_name.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,downloadFile);
function downloadFile (evtObj:Event):void 
{
    var Location:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    Location.url = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";

    var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
    fr.download(request);       
}
```

Comment: Thank you putvande, but unfortunately this has not seemed to solve my problem.  Both the .zip and video files do not react at all now when clicked, neither in Safari or Firefox.  Any other ideas?